# Do you know any Vaishnava Kundalini Yoga Guru?

Tags: vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, yoga, guru, kundalini

Namaste,
I am searching for a Vaishnava Guru who teaches Kundalini Yoga. Most Gurus, (With Due respect) I know teach either Advaita or Shaivism/Shaktism or a combination of both. But I am searching for a Vaishnava Guru who teaches Kundalini Yoga with just pure techniques. Please let me know if anyone knows a Vaishnava Guru?